# What exactly is the lack of transparency in systemd?

Tags: systemd

Is [the claim](https://lists.debian.org/debian-amd64/2014/10/msg00019.html) that `systemd` log files have *"a complete lack of simplicity and transparency*" about their being binary files or because the binary files are difficult to parse and understand or because they are actually undocumented? The same question applies to the configuration files which I guess are replacing scripts. If I were to go and try to write a parser using, say, lex/awk to read the files would I find that a 3 hour job, or would it take weeks?

Comment: What claim is that? Where is the context?

Comment: @Braiam - the context is right there in the question - *`systemd` log files*.

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, but where is this claim coming from? In Wikipedia terms: `[by whom?]`

Comment: Google? For example, https://lists.debian.org/debian-amd64/2014/10/msg00019.html or any of a million other forum posts. Quote: "a complete lack of simplicity and transparency" right out of this forum thread, and you can find dozens of others just like it.

Comment: @muru - ahh, `[by whom]` is clearer - which is somewhat ironic in *context*. Tyler Durden - *Google?* is probably not a good assumption - the point of this site is to fully encapsulate a question and answer of possible interest to many as well as can be done in easily digestible, short-essay form. Or, at least, that' what I take from it.

Comment: @TylerDurden I have read enough Debian mailing list fights about systemd to fill a relationship, so thanks, but I am not going to open that link.

Comment: @Braiam - does the edit satisfy?

Comment: @muru - given the trend there, I'm willing to bet there is a long way to go before any of those involved will have had *enough*. Strangest to me, though, is that they all compete so fiercely for their idea of what should comprise the *distribution* - which is only a loosely defined collection of otherwise freely available and customizable components. If any of them has a disagreement with what someone else wants to package together, what is stopping them from packing their own suitcase *(so to speak)*?

Comment: @mikeserv Don't go down that road either! :P Mike (presumably?), meet [Devuan](https://devuan.org/).

Comment: The first rule of systemd is *not* to talk about systemd...

Comment: @jasonwryan - pithy, as always.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the question, the answer is the former alternative. A log file is most useful for debug work - and debugging is most likely occurring in the company of a bug or two.

A bug is *(by definition)* unintended and *(by convention)* unwanted behavior in a system. And so as the *bug* prevents the system from working as intended, then the log that assists the debugging should be as transparently accessible as possible. This is why logs are conventionally *(and arguably most usefully)* plain text files.

If, for whatever reason, the bug affects the operation of the logger, and the logger is the only means of accessing the log, then debugging only becomes that much more complicated. This only gets more complicated when the logger is incorporated into the init component of the system in question.

As to how long it might take you - that is entirely dependent on the bug that affects you - which is almost always an unknown quantity.

And about the latter alternative - *are they undocumented*? The true answer is that there is no such thing as *undocumented* *open-source* code. The code itself, as a last alternative, is self-documenting in every case. `systemd` and its components, though, are typically documented fairly well - despite its aggressive release cycle.

Of course, it is often undesirable to sort through hundreds of pages of documentation for an answer to an obscure question which you have yet even to fully understand the form of asking - and it is almost always the questions we don't yet know how to ask correctly that result in the errors we insert into our code.